# I am trying to split a large csv into individual .txt files by row, WITH a header in each .txt in R

Tags: r, csv, split

I am trying to create a separate .txt file for each row in a .csv in R studio. I found the csv2txt function, but I cannot figure out how to edit it to retain the header information in each .txt.

Using the below code:

```
csv2txt <- function(mydir, labels = 1){
  mycsvfile <- list.files(mydir, full.names = TRUE, pattern = "*.CSV|.csv")
  mycsvdata <- read.csv(mycsvfile)
  mytxtsconcat <- apply(mycsvdata[-(1:labels)], 1, paste, collapse=" ")
  mytxtsdf <- data.frame(filename = mycsvdata[,labels], # get the first col for the text file names
                         fulltext = mytxtsconcat) 
  setwd(mydir)
  invisible(lapply(1:nrow(mytxtsdf), function(i) write.table(mytxtsdf[i,2], 
                                                             file = paste0(mytxtsdf[i,1], ".txt"),
                                                             row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE,
                                                             quote = FALSE)))
  message(paste0("Your text files can be found in ", getwd()))
}
```

I get output that looks like this:

```
HILTON - ABERGIS CAYE AMBERGIS CAYE, BELIZE  0.47 0.35 0.31 0.82 0.74 0.52 0.69 0.88 0.71 0.88 0.68
```

The .csv has this header at the top:

```
Hotel   Area    Overall Satisfaction for Location   Overall Property Satisfaction   Property Appearance Add'tl Item Working Order   Property Maintenance    Staff Knowledge Staff Interaction   Safety/Security Check In/Out    Invoice Accuracy    Bed Quality
```

That I would like to have in every .txt.

Does anyone know how I would edit the code to do this? Or know of a function that will do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that your csv has a header row that isn't separated by commas?

Comment: @AllanCameron, Hi Allan, yes, it's in there. I think it's the col.names=FALSE that is making it not appear, but I tried making that true and then it just gave me one x at the top, because I guess that requires additional code to concatenate like it does with the other rows that I couldn't figure out how to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is having a similar issue, here is what I ended up doing.

I forced headers into col.names, which isn't ideal because they don't line up exactly in the .txt. But my workaround was adding | between elements, so then I can open the .txt in excel, separate by a custom delimiter, and then you end up with properly aligned columns.

Code below.

```
# Make the .csv into separate .txt files
csv2txt <- function(mydir, labels = 1){
  
  # Get the names of all the CSV file
  mycsvfile <- list.files(mydir, full.names = TRUE, pattern = "*.CSV|.csv")
  
  # Read the actual contexts of the text files into R and rearrange a little.
  
  # create a list of dataframes containing the text
  mycsvdata <- read.csv(mycsvfile)
  
  # combine all except the first column together into
  # one long character string for each row
  mytxtsconcat <- apply(mycsvdata[-(1:labels)], 1, paste, collapse=" | ")
  
  # make a dataframe with the file names and texts
  mytxtsdf <- data.frame(filename = mycsvdata[,labels], # get the first col for the text file names
                         fulltext = mytxtsconcat)
  
  # Now write one text file for each row of the csv
  # use 'invisible' so we don't see anything in the console
  
  setwd(mydir)
  invisible(lapply(1:nrow(mytxtsdf), function(i) write.table(mytxtsdf[i,2], 
                                                             file = paste0(mytxtsdf[i,1], ".txt"),
                                                             row.names = FALSE, col.names = " HOTEL (Q15 1) | METRO AREA STATE (Q10 1)  | Overall Location Satisfaction | Overall Property Satisfaction | Property Appearance | Add'tl Item Working Order | Property Maintenance | Staff Knowledge | Staff Interaction | Safety/Security | Check In/Out | Invoice Accuracy | Bed Quality",
                                                             quote = FALSE)))
  
  # now check your folder to see the txt files
  message(paste0("Your text files can be found in ", getwd()))
}
```